# Cannot Logon to Drupal ("The website encountered an error while retrieving...")

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am trying to get a new Drupal site running on Ubuntu 12.10.  I believe I have what is either an Apache or permissions error.  I can get to the main logon page for the site, but after entering my credentials, I get the following error.

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/node?destination=node. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

I set my permissions using the following script, and my apache setup is below that.  Can anyone tell me where else to look?

```
!/bin/bash

FILES="/var/www/localdrupal/cms/sites/default/files"
SETTINGS="/var/www/localdrupal/cms/sites/default/settings.php"
SITES="/var/www/localdrupal/cms/sites"
DEFAULT="/var/www/localdrupal/cms/sites/default"
THEMES="/var/www/localdrupal/cms/sites/all/themes"
MODULES="/var/www/localdrupal/cms/sites/all/modules"
DSETTINGS="/var/www/localdrupal/cms/sites/default/default.settings.php"

# Paths for binary files
TAR="/bin/tar"
RM="/bin/rm"
CHOWN="/bin/chown"
FIND="/bin/find"
CHMOD="/bin/chmod"

# Change permissions to be secure

$CHOWN -R www-data:www-data ${SITES}
$CHMOD 775 ${SITES}
$CHMOD 775 ${FILES}
$CHMOD g+w -R ${FILES}
$CHMOD 440 ${SETTINGS}
$CHMOD 440 ${DSETTINGS}
$CHMOD 755 ${DEFAULT}
$CHMOD 755 -R ${THEMES}
$CHMOD 755 -R ${MODULES}
```

Apache:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localdrupal/cms
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride  None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/localdrupal/cms/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Can you go to http://localhost/cms/node ? and try to login from there

Comment: did you check if you have enable rewrite module for apache, also check if you have enable suphp, modsecurity, if you are running the right php version, you should check your logs in apache for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Check your setup.php, probably you should set the baseurl variable there, since your drupal root is not the default /var/www